# Extract every nth row in one column based on the same values in a different column

Tags: r

I want to make a new dataframe where I extract every 2nd row from NM where the time column is the same. I also want to do something similar where I extract every 50th row too.

DF:

```
NM    A         File                                  Condition   Time
638 -0.0019     No_oil 105min time17-50 13,319s.csv      No_oil   125
639 -0.0017     No_oil 105min time17-50 13,319s.csv      No_oil   125
640 -0.0017     No_oil 105min time17-50 13,319s.csv      No_oil   125
638 -0.0019     No_oil 105min time17-50 13,319s.csv      No_oil   105
639 -0.0017     No_oil 105min time17-50 13,319s.csv      No_oil   105
640 -0.0017     No_oil 105min time17-50 13,319s.csv      No_oil   105
```

Desired DF:

```
NM    A         File                                  Condition   Time
638 -0.0019     No_oil 105min time17-50 13,319s.csv      No_oil   125
640 -0.0017     No_oil 105min time17-50 13,319s.csv      No_oil   125
638 -0.0019     No_oil 105min time17-50 13,319s.csv      No_oil   105
640 -0.0017     No_oil 105min time17-50 13,319s.csv      No_oil   105
```

I've tried: NewDF.df <- ODF.df[seq(1, nrow(ODF.df), by=50), ] but because in nm it goes 640,638 when there's a new time, it doesn't work. 
Thanks.

Comment: There are lots of dupes for this `library(dplyr); library(data.table); df1 %>% group_by(File, Condition, Time, A1 = rleid(A)) %>% slice(1)` or `setDT(df1)[,  head(.SD, 1),.(File, Condition, Time, A1 = rleid(A))]`

Comment: When I do this: D50.Data.df <- D.Data.df %>% group_by(File, Condition, Time, A1 = rleid(D.Data.df$X.nm.), X.A.) %>% slice(1). I get the following error: Error: All columns must be named